Where would the B wire connect to a smart Ecobee thermostat?
I have a Honeywell Chronotherm III thermostat, but do not have batteries installed.  I am trying to figure out if I have a C wire connection.  The thermostat is working, and has 5 wires. However, the blue wire is connected to the B terminal, not the C. The other 4 wires: Red to R, White to W, Green to G and Yellow to Y. Would the B wire connected to the B be my common wire?

use multimeter do you get 24 volt between the R and B

Do you have a heat pump?

The old therm is working without battery so you do have the Common wire.
Blue wire is connected to the B terminal,- that would be the C wire
Red to R,-is the hot (24 Volt)
White to W - is the Heating command
Green to G - is the Fan command
Yellow to Y - is the Cooling command
